# Bundler strip basic auth from source url

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I have a geminabox server that I connect as source like:

```
source 'https://user:pswd@example.com/'
```

After running a bundle install the versioned Gemfile.lock is updated and as remote endpoint I find:

```
remote: https://example.com
```

I need of course to preserve the basic auth info in the source url. Anyone saw this?

Bundler 1.6.2, Gem 2.3.0

Update:
I just discovered that the .lock file gets overwritten with the stepped url even after a rails server or rails console command.

Comment: You may store the credentials in you local bundler config with `bundle config https://example.com/ user:pswd`, so you won't have to check in the credentials into your repo. Read more about it in the newest man version: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/8c7283921ea444528e0bb333efd52ff518a0dbb9/man/bundle-config.ronn#L160

Comment: This looks like a good advise but I noted that my issue what happening just on ruby 1.9.3-p545 ....it does not happen with any other ruby

Comment: Could be in connection with https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3045 ?

Comment: I do not think so but worth asking there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug. The credentials are read from the `Gemfile`, not `Gemfile.lock`. Are you having trouble actually running Bundler?